# Is there a way to use arbitary implemented methods of extended Actor classes in an akka app?

Tags: scala, akka-actor

In my situation, I have an Actor class (say Greeter) with a `sendSecureMessage` method that I want to use in the app. The problem is after the creation of a greeter actor, ActorSystem provides me with just an `ActorRef` reference to `Greeter` and I can't use `sendSecureMessage` with that reference.
is there a way in which I can call this function?

```
def sendSecureMessage(sender: ActorRef,receiver: ActorRef, message: Any, automata: Automata):
```

that's the method in `class Greeter(message: String, printerActor: ActorRef) extends Actor`

and this is how I create the actors:

```
  val firstActor: ActorRef =
       system.actorOf(Greeter.props("first",printer).withDispatcher("custom-dispatcher"),"firstActor")
```

Comment: If there is also something wrong with this and we should only implement Receive function in Actor Class let me know so I can describe the problem more clearly and what led me  to this decision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options here.

If `sendSecureMessage` is a "static" method that does not use actor state, then put it in the companion object for the actor and call it directly from there.

If `sendSecureMessage` does use actor state then the only safe way to call it is to send a message with the parameters to the actor, have the actor call the method, then send the results back as a reply. If you allow code to call methods on the actor from a different thread then all the synchronisation guarantees go out of the window.

Comment: thanks so much for the clarification. Does the second option come with performance issues?

Comment: It is certainly slower than a direct call, so it depends on how often this is happening. Also, there is no need to send a reply if the result of the method is not needed. As always, make it work, make it robust, then worry about making it fast.

Answer (score 2):

Actors are isolated from any "public" access and meant to be used just via messages. This is the reason why you get only an `ActorRef` when creating an actor.

You can still share code of the method `sendSecureMessage` under the condition that it's not accessing any internal actor fields, ie `context` for example.

You could extract method `sendSecureMessage` into companion object of `Greeter` as following and use this method from other places without the need of having an `ActorRef`.

```scala
object Greeter {
  def sendSecureMessage(sender: ActorRef, receiver: ActorRef, message: Any, automata: Automata)
}
```

If method does access internal actor fields/data, you should introduce a message that calls this method.